# Mac OS Automator pdf to jpg quick action not working

Tags: macos, pdf, jpeg, automator

I produce pdf's from jpg's and vice versa all the time by right clicking on the file and using "Quick Actions" produced using Mac's Automator.

But while the workflow I use to produce pdf's works perfectly, the workflow to produce jpg's always gives me duplicate files. I've tried everything I can think of but I always get either no jpg produced or 2 of them. The illustrations below show each of my workflows, with comment bubbles on the presence or absence of the "Copy Finder Items" action which seems to be key.

Thanks.

Workflow to produce jpgs (makes duplicates):
[image]

Workflow to produce pdfs (works perfectly):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. When I removed the "Get Selected Finder Items" action I no longer got duplicate jpg's.

The process of posting a question helps me a lot. Maybe this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.... this was happening to me. I noticed the 4 files I was trying to convert to pdf by quick action one of the files was a "txt" file by accident and not a pdf. which is why i didn't get the "Create PDF" option. make sure your files are correct!